# Installing Mozilla extension from command line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mozilla

I have an extension for Thunderbird that I'd like to install automatically from a script - since I have to do it on all our workstations - is there a way to do that?
Thanks!

(Ubuntu 9.04)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taken from [Mozillazine](https://web.archive.org/web/20100617192805/http://forums.mozillazine.org:80/viewtopic.php?p=1241506)...

Generic Install

```
firefox.exe -install-global-extension extension.xpi
```

Specific Profile

```
firefox.exe -profile "path to profile folder" -install-global-extension extension.xpi
```

Batch Install

```
for %%e in ("path to extensions\*.xpi") do "firefox.exe" -install-global-extension "%%e"
for %%e in ("path to themes\*.jar") do "firefox.exe" -install-global-theme "%%e"
```

Someone in the thread asserts they work for Thunderbird in the same manner.

Answer (score 4):

Check [this post](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=1241506) out, might help you.

Comment: Ahh, sorry just realized my answer is the same exact content as what you linked.  +rep

Comment: The problem with link-only answers...: _The requested topic does not exist._ Now [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100617192805/http://forums.mozillazine.org:80/viewtopic.php?p=1241506) but probably extremely old.

Answer (score 4):

The command line option `-install-global-extension` has been [deprecated as of Gecko 1.9.2, FF 3.6.x, TB 3.1.x](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Installing_extensions).

Mozilla now suggest to:

> Copy the `.xpi` file into the `<installation_directory>\extensions` folder.

Answer (score 2):

Here http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/271-ubuntu-firefox-thunderbird-addon-commandline is `mozilla-extension-manager` bash script that can automate downloading xpi file, installing and removing Mozilla Firefox extensions (local or globally) via cli (command line) commands without gui.